# Screen Time "App Limits" do not sync between iPhone and Mac

Tags: iphone, ios, mac, screen-time

I am trying to enable screen time app usage limit on my devices. When I am asked to choose the affected apps and websites on my iPhone, I can pick programs installed on my Mac, which implies that this limitation should work on the laptop as well. The problem is that it does not appear on the mac after I enable it on the iPhone, although the "share screen time across devices" setting is enabled on both devices. Thanks in advance!